# -15 of reputation. where to check, why?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation went down](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/reputation-went-down)

I've got -15 today - but I even cannot see in my profile why. If I look there everything is empty for today - but if I click on the dropdown near my name at the top of the page there is -15 for the reputation today.

Comment: It looks like someone un-accepted an answer you've given.

Comment: You mean he accepted it before and then accepted another answer?

Comment: The former, yes, but one can un-accept (by clicking the green checkmark) without accepting another answer.

Comment: ok, I meant the same. Yes, this maybe the case (anyway I will not look for this person).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/n-8-log-2n-forgot-basic-math). The OP had accepted your answer as being the "first answer." Bill Dubuque mentioned in comments that one is encouraged to accept the "best answer" (I tend to phrase it as "the answer you found most helpful").

Before you ask about how to discover this in general, it's been asked before (e.g., [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/identifying-a-dis-accepted-answer) and in questions linked there). There isn't a way.

Comment: My intent was to discourage the practice of using "quickest" as a primary criterion for answer acceptance. I advised the OP to use answer acceptance as a way to help guide readers to the answer that was "best". It seems this caused the OP to change his accepted choice (to Arturo's answer). It's my opinion that answers are generally accepted too quickly, with the result that often (later-appearing) best answers are not strongly correlated to accepted answers (whether or not "best" is judged by the OP or the community).

Comment: [It is in fact possible to confirm that you were right](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/31548/timeline). (Your answer was accepted on 8 April at 6:44:33, Gortaur's answer was unaccepted 3 seconds earlier.)

Comment: @Hendrik: I didn't know about the timeline page. Thanks!