# When is it possible to see the voting history

Tags: support, timeline

When I asked a question here: [-15 of reputation. where to check, why?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/15-of-reputation-where-to-check-why) Hendrik provided the timeline page showing the voting history: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/31548/timeline

Is it known how to find such a timeline page for your answer/question? In the path for the question it's not just sufficient to put `question`$\to$`posts` and add `/timeline` after the number.

Comment: I presume you've seen [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/2936#2936)?

Comment: @J.M. yes, but as far as I understand, there is written only about the disacceptance of an answer.

Comment: The substitution algorithm should work exactly as you say - for which question do you have problems?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: checked it out again - now it works. I thought I made a mistake somehow the last time, and since I wasn't sure how should it work, I never repeat. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Voting history through timeline is functional on non-deleted question using the address of:

```
math.stackexchange.com/posts/<questionid>/timeline
```

There is one thing that may trip things up, however, and that's that you *must* specify a question ID. This is a bit different than what one might think sometimes because for example, if you want to see the revision history of a post, you can specify an `<answerid>` to look at an answer. The timeline, however, only works when looking at questions (it will tell you the votes for all answers to that question, though).

If one keeps that in mind, it should work as long as the question is not deleted. It is currently not possible to view the timeline of a deleted question.

---

For those who are capable of it, [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view/72917#72917) contains a couple scripts and such that you can implement that will provide a link to the timeline view without requiring URL manipulation.

Comment: Is there some reason why we have to jump through hoops vs. having an exposed link?

Comment: @BillDubuque because that view is not currently maintained, is not easy to read and does not add much that isn't available otherwise given enough reputation