# Where reputation disappears

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-tab

Is there any possibility to deduce why 25 of (my) reputation disappeared probably this night? It is not the problem of reputation, but the lack of information is rather strange. On tex.stackexchange.com I could see negative changes in the reputation history. What about this feature on math.stackexchange.com?

I have not found the answer here [Reputation went down](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/reputation-went-down).

Comment: I concur that on TeX.SX we always know why we lose every single point.

Comment: someone prob removed your question or answer.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21311/i-had-reputation-of-104-it-fell-down-to-96-the-next-time-i-logged-in-why-is-tha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check show removed post. It seems that this is set by default on TeX.SX since I never checked it but on Math.SX it isn't set. By checking it, you will see the removed post appear in the list.

[image]

Click reputation, scroll to bottom, and check the box.

Comment: Ah, there is a difference in the defaults.

Comment: @robjohn I have been ponder this too for some time. I just never asked but at least it is cleared up now.

Comment: @dustin Yes, yes, yes! (As ex-prime minister Marcinkiewicz said).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I was always curious too why I was losing rep too. I just never asked or had to urge to look until into the difference of TeX and Math until you asked.

Answer (score 9):

The question [Compute largest integer power of $6$ that divides $73!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996647/compute-largest-integer-power-of-6-that-divides-73) was deleted, and so the reputation you received from it disappeared.

Comment: I think @przemyslawscherwentke is wondering why it doesn't say that in his reputation list since it would say that on TeX.SX.

Comment: I don't know of any difference in the reputation handling here vs other SE sites. Perhaps it has to do with ability to see things due to reputation. Someone else might know if there is some difference between the sites.

Comment: Thank you! (Yes, I know that we are thanking by upvoting).