# How can I find out why my reputation score decreased?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, reputation-tab

On a few occasions I find that my reputation score has decreased by a few points, presumably because an answer I once gave was down-voted.

It would be nice to know which answer was down-voted so that I could re-examine it.

Is there any way to discover which answer was down-voted?

Comment: The profiles have a [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/246513/john-wayland-bales?tab=reputation), where you can look up what caused your reputation changes. If you check the "show deleted posts" box at the bottom, it will also display (to you) reputation events caused by the deletion of posts.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your response. I did not know the answer was so simple.

Comment: See also: [Where reputation disappears](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18884). (I am not sure, but perhaps it could be even considered duplicate. At least it seems that a few [somewhat similar posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/18884) has been closed as duplicates of that one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Daniel Fischer said in the comments.  Alternatively, when viewing the desktop version of the site you can click the achievements icon near the top and you'll see where you lost rep.  In the example below, you'll see that today I was downvoted (thus getting $-2$) on an old question of mine here and on a puzzle I posted on Puzzling.SE.  Not my finest day, indeed!

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I checked my "achievements" list and did not see it at first because I had to scroll all the way to the bottom. The problem with looking at the link on one's profile page is that it may be many months back. The achievement list is much quicker.