# how to fully track reputation changes

Tags: support, reputation

I've been reading extensively [Where reputation disappears](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18884/309917) but in the end I'm still unable to fully follow my reputation changes. In particular the latest I observed was the loss occured exactly at the moment I'm writing: my reputation passed from 3034 to 3019. (I have "show removed posts" checkbox checked). Is there anyone that can have a look?

---

It follows the screenshot of a page yet not refreshed where my reputation before the loss is displayed

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind, a picture of your reputation page would be nice.

Comment: Looks like you've lost 15 rep.  Have you noticed whether one of your (accepted answers) was recently unaccepted? (-15),

Comment: @amWhy I believe we would be able to see this, check his August 19th rep changes.

Comment: Unless perhaps there is a delay in the rep tab, in which this may be possible.

Comment: Errrr, @SimplyBeautifulArt, "his August 19th rep changes" ?

Comment: @amWhy When I check, I see an "unaccepted (-15)"

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/309917/trying?tab=reputation and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swui5.png

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @SimplyBeautifulArt. So in the end I need to check manually for all items in the reputation page because there is no way to get reputation changes ordered by modification time

Comment: That's what I expected, but the loss from Aug 19th would have already been accounted for in trying's rep.  We're talking about a change roughly one hour ago.

Comment: @trying No, I believe unaccepts or ordered by when they were unaccepted.

Comment: When did you notice this rep change?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt just five minute before asking this question

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be that upvotes and accepts have a short grace period in which they do not appear in the rep tab when removed.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ok, I got it. Anyway it is a little inconvenient, because it would be interesting for a user to try to improve his/her own answer when it is unaccepted, but for this to be possible the user would have to be able, at least, to know what has been unaccepted as easily as possible. Thanks to you and amWhy for your insights, I will go through my reputation list if this happens again.

Comment: Note that I am unsure if this is the case, merely speculation.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes, I got it. Indeed, in the meanwhile it has just popped up in my mind that on Aug 19th I saw online the reputation loss of 15 and I was able to deduce at the time that it was due to an unaccepted answer just occurred.