# Reputation went down.

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation  went down 170 points before 5 minutes

Also it has gone down many times,

I have almost lost  1000 reputation and I cannot see the deleted posts.

What is going on?

It is not about reputation but, ok 170 rep in an instant is weird.

I understand that is someone answers low quality posts of new uses then the answer may be deleted, so you lose rep from there and I try not to answer low quality posts, or users with some rep that I believe they dedicate time to contribute to this site.

So what do I have to do to maintain my rep? Do I have to answer question from users with, more than 10000 rep in order not to lose 1000 rep in one month?

Comment: No sir, of course not. You should not discriminate just because someone does not have more than 10k. What I think you _should_ do is not to answer PSQ nor duplicated ones. Because believe it or not, well writen questions (but duplicated) with helpful answers, are likely to be deleted too.

Comment: Doesn’t it show in the reputation tab?

Comment: It seems that a few of your posts were deleted.

Comment: clearly you haven't given out large bounties like I have. 500 in one go potentially.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I have not given any bounties

Comment: Its ok...i will just be more selective to which questions i answer..i cannot do anything else.

Comment: Since you are above 10k, you should be able to see your deleted posts [by searching for deleted:1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=deleted%3a1). See also here: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)  To keep track of your reputation, it is useful to use the checkbox "show removed post" on [your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation). See also: [Where reputation disappears](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18884).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is going on?

Seven questions with the tag [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) you answered were in three recent deletion lists of the CRUDE room:[1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52933315#52933315),[2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52913797#52913797),[3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52905715#52905715). They have been deleted:

- [Uniformly Convergent Series and Bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471638/9464) (1 vote)
- [$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1^{10}+2^{10}+...+n^{10}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3469737/9464) (4 votes)
- [Find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3468456/9464) (6 votes)
- [Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{5780}k^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3468338/9464) (1 vote)
- [Proving an integral with the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433347/9464) (2 votes)
- [Definition of $\sum$ as a supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3423542/9464) (1 vote)
- [Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1 + x^{\frac {\sqrt {n}}{ \ln (n + 1)}}\right)^{-1} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3468779/9464) (2 votes)

This explains your 170 missing reps.

Comment: I did not know that the question where on a deletion list..i will try to be more selective to what posts i answer..

Comment: @MariosGretsas: When you have 20k reps, you could [vote to undelete](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) deleted posts when you find appropriate.

Comment: I understand..but it is wiser to vote for undeletion more interesting and important posts than those you mentioned now..i should not answered those.

Comment: @MariosGretsas: That is a matter of taste. To identify duplicates, one can use Approach0; see also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site

Comment: Οκ...thank you..i can guess some questions whether are duplicates..but i should not answer question with minimum effort even if the O.P has an adequate amount of rep.

Comment: @MariosGretsas: I'm not sure what you mean by "adequate amount of rep." When you find a question not good, you could vote to close it.