# Request for explanation of rep change due to recent answer of mine

Tags: support, reputation

Today I see a $-15 $  change in my Reputation  due to my recent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626761/for-what-of-n-do-we-have-an-le-bncn/2627949#2627949) but it does not say "User was removed" and my A has no votes and no comments. So I am wondering what happened.

Comment: Your answer was [unaccepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/254665/danielwainfleet?tab=reputation)

Comment: In earlier days this seems to have been difficult to spot.  See the old [discussion here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/identifying-a-dis-accepted-answer/2936#2936).